# Error 502.3 al recibir la respuesta de un metodo POST asycrono C# Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-post, iis-express

Hola tengo dos proyectos una **FE** y otro **BE** de .NET Core que ambos corren con IIS Express.
Desde el proyecto FE estoy ejecutando un metodo por **HttpPost** de forma asyncrona.
Veo que que la conexión entre APIs es correcta y desde la API BE me devuelve de forma rápida el JSON de respuesta, pero cuando llega al metodo **GetServicePostAsync** que tiene que procesar la data ahi el PostAsync termina dando el error indicado 502.3.

**A continuación pongo el método que lanza el error:**

```
 public async Task<T4> GetServicePostAsync<T4>(Object urlParameters, string uriString, string api, int minutesTimeout = 10) where T4 : class
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Debug($"BEGIN SERVICE CALL - GetServicePutAsync method - UriString: {uriString}, Api: {api}");

            using (HttpClient client = await HttpClientHelper.CreateAsync())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriString);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutesTimeout);

                var postContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(urlParameters),
                                                    Encoding.UTF8,
                                                    "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(api, postContent).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T4>();
                }
                
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    await ThrowServiceApiResponseException(response, uriString, this.AppSettings);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.Debug($"END SERVICE CALL - GetServicePutAsync method - UriString: {uriString}, Api: {api}");
        }
    }
```

**Y este es el error que me lanza:**

```html
One or more errors occurred. (<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 502.3 - Bad Gateway</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 
 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
  <h3>HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway</h3> 
  <h4>Se superó un límite interno de tamaño de encabezados de respuesta
</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Causas más probables:</h4> 
  <ul>  <li>La aplicación CGI no devolvió un conjunto válido de errores HTTP.</li>  <li>Un servidor que actúa como proxy o puerta de enlace no pudo procesar la solicitud debido a un error en una puerta de enlace primaria.</li> </ul> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Qué puede intentar:</h4> 
  <ul>  <li>Use DebugDiag para solucionar los problemas de la aplicación CGI.</li>  <li>Determine si un proxy o una puerta de enlace es responsable de este error.</li> </ul> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
  <div id="details-left"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetCoreModuleV2</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x80072f96</td></tr> 
     
   </table> 
  </div> 
  <div id="details-right"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://localhost:44339/api/Presupuestacion/importarArchivoExcel/SemiFijos/S</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\REPO_SIC\sic_cross_maestro_be\Maestro_be\api\Presupuestacion\importarArchivoExcel\SemiFijos\S</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anónimo</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anónimo</td></tr> 
     
   </table> 
   <div class="clear"></div> 
  </div> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
  Este error se produce cuando una aplicación CGI no devuelve un conjunto válido de encabezados HTTP o cuando un proxy o una puerta de enlace no pudo enviar la solicitud a una puerta de enlace primaria. Si no es un problema de CGI, puede que tenga que realizar un seguimiento de la red o ponerse en contacto con el administrador del servidor. 
  <p><a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=502,3,0x80072f96,22621">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
   
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html> 
)
```

Si bien el error es claro, no se cómo solucionarlo porque ya borre cache y la prueba que estoy haciendo es bien sencilla no contine tanta data y como comentaba la repsuesta desde la API de BE anda bastante rapida no llega a medio minuto.

Como comentario adicional el error solamente me da de forma local, porque deployando en el ambiente de pruebas no lanza el error y ada super rapido con mucho mas volumen de datos.

Quisiera saber si alguien tiene le ha pasado y como sloucionarno, pues me ayudaría mucho seguir trabajando de forma local para validar todo antes de enviar a ambiente de prueba.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Estoy algo confundido, finalmente quien te manda el error?

Comment: El error lo envia el cliente de FE cuanod recibe la respuesta de BE y trata de procesarla. Esta línea para ser exactos HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(api, postContent).Result;  Intuyo que debe ser algo de mi IIS Express, peor no estoy del todo segura :(

Comment: Buenas, que cantidad de parametros estás enviando hacía el API? la información enviada por medio de QueryString tiene un limite máximo establecido, de enviar muchos datos, te aconsejo configurar tu API para recibir los datos por medio del Body y así reducir la cantidad de parametros por medio del querystring enviados